# Docker - Inbound network access to host stops when new network is created

Tags: docker

Anytime I create a new docker network on the host, I loose inbound network access. If I have an active SSH session it boots me off. The only way to restore it is to delete the network.

```
[admin@server1 ~]$ docker version
Client:
 Version:      17.06.0-ce
 API version:  1.30
 Go version:   go1.8.3
 Git commit:   02c1d87
 Built:        Fri Jun 23 21:20:36 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:      17.06.0-ce
 API version:  1.30 (minimum version 1.12)
 Go version:   go1.8.3
 Git commit:   02c1d87
 Built:        Fri Jun 23 21:21:56 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
 Experimental: false

[admin@server1 ~]$ uname -a
Linux server1 3.10.0-514.26.2.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Jul 4 15:04:05 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

[admin@server1 ~]$ cat /etc/centos-release
CentOS Linux release 7.3.1611 (Core)
```

Comment: Upgrade to the latest version and test and if still issue persists then open a issue on docker

Comment: That worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Upgraded to latest version as Tarun suggested and it fixed the issue.

```
[root@server1 ~]# docker --version
Docker version 17.06.2-ce, build cec0b72
```